# Need to check an answer

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, word-problem

At a fast food restaurant, a milk shake costs $r$.  A chicken sandwich costs 3 times as much as the shake.  A large order of French fries costs $\$3$.  If $r-2$, how much do 3 chicken sandwiches and 2 large orders of French fries cost?

The answer I get is $\$24$ but the answer book says $\$22$ and I cannot figure out how it is $\$22$?

Thanks.

Comment: The book is wrong and you are right. A simple typo in the book.

Answer (score 0):

> At a fast food restaurant, a milk shake costs r . A chicken sandwich costs 3 times as much as the shake. A large order of French fries costs \$3 . If r=2 , how much do 3 chicken sandwiches and 2 large orders of French fries cost?

We have $3(3r)+ 2(3) = 9r+6$

If $r=2$ this is $9r+6 = 24$, as you stated.

> The answer I get is \$24  but the answer book says \$22  and I cannot figure out how it is \$22 ?

The reason is a typographical error in the textbook.